# Is there any way to regexp-quote a string in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, google-chrome, v8

I want to create a regexp that matches exactly the string *foo*, even if *foo* contains metacharacters. This is sometimes known as `RegExp.quote`. Is there a way to do this in a Node.js environment (or, more broadly, v8/Chrome/WebKit/JavaScript)?

Comment: If what you want is a `RegExp.quote` function, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks, Dan! I packaged that up into an NPM module (see answer below).

Comment: Note that we're currently [working on adding this functionality to JavaScript](https://github.com/benjamingr/RegExp.escape) if you have an opinion about it please join the discussion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`npm install regexp-quote`

```
RegExp.quote = require('regexp-quote') // optional
new RegExp(RegExp.quote(foo))
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It is completely alright that the OP answered his own question.

Comment: Thanks for packaging it into a library. Very neat :)